# How to force Container to have its child's height in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I do not want to give my `Container` widget a specific number as `height` (10, 50, 500 etc.). Instead, I want it to take the height of its child. How can I achieve that?

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Dialog(
        child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset("assets/ad.png"),
                Text('some text here'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

A container first surrounds the child with padding (inflated by any borders present in the decoration) and then applies additional constraints to the padded extent (incorporating the width and height as constraints, if either is non-null). The container is then surrounded by additional empty space described from the margin.

During painting, the container first applies the given transform, then paints the decoration to fill the padded extent, then it paints the child, and finally paints the foregroundDecoration, also filling the padded extent.

Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be as small as possible. **Containers with children size themselves to their children**. The width, height, and constraints arguments to the constructor override this.

read more from [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)